# XML Parser return specific nodes

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, linq-to-xml

I have XML like that

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<customers>
  <customer>
    <date>22 Aug 2014</date>
    <name>Kevin Anders</name>
    <phone>555.555.5555</phone>
  </customer>
  <customer>
    <date>23 Aug 2014</date>
    <name>Staci Richard</name>
    <phone>555.122.1552</phone>
  </customer>
  <customer>
    <date>25 Aug 2014</date>
  </customer>
</customers>
```

In the XML some nodes are missing but date node is present in every element. I have around 200 of  nodes but i want to parse the xml based on date and just need to return top 4 dates. For example today is 16 june then my xml get the latest date node and return next three days matching nodes. I am able to parse the nodes but not sure how to return top nodes based on date

```
public static IEnumerable<Customer> StreamBooks(string uri) 
{
    using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(uri))
    {
        string name = null;
        string phone = null;

        reader.MoveToContent();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element
                && reader.Name == "customer")
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                     if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element &&
                         reader.Name == "name")
                     {
                         name = reader.ReadString();
                         break;
                     }
                }
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element &&
                        reader.Name == "phone")
                    {
                        phone = reader.ReadString();
                        break;
                    }
                }
                yield return new Customer() { Name = name, Phone  = phone };
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, do you understand the use of `OrderBy` and `OrderByDescending`? Do you understand how to parse a date from a string? (This is not a good date format to use, by the way - I'd change it if you can.) Do you understand how to limit the results of a LINQ query using `Take`? What have you tried so far?

Comment: i have updated my question and added XML parser to read the xml

Comment: string uri = @"D:\CSV\test.xml"; // your big XML file

            foreach (var book in XmlHelper.StreamBooks(uri))
            {
              
            }

Comment: So you're not actually using LINQ to XML to start with? Why is your question tagged with LINQ to XML?

Comment: i can use linq to xml as well. If there is better way to solve it then i can use it but i found that solution

Comment: Well it's not clear what you're trying to achieve here - fetching the most recent 4 `Customer` objects, or fetching the XML nodes representing them? (Using LINQ to XML would be *much* simpler than your current code, by the way.) And you still haven't answered *any* of the questions in my first comment.

Comment: i am sorry i am new to programming and i have not used OrderBy or OrderByDescending. Yo can change date format . If it can be simple using linq to xml then i would love to use that code. My scenario is that i have around 200 elements and i want to get only 4 top date elemenets from my xml .Is it clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd start off by removing your current code to retrieve a sequence of customers, and instead just use LINQ to XML:

```
var customers = XDocument.Load(uri)
                         .Root.Elements("customer")
                         .Select(x => new Customer {
                                     Date = (DateTime) x.Element("date"),
                                     Name = (string) x.Element("name"),
                                     Phone = (string) x.Element("phone")
                                 });
```

This requires you to change your date format to "yyyy-MM-dd" which is a standard XML date format. (So "2014-08-23" instead of "23 Aug 2014" for example.)

If you *have* to keep the existing date format, you can use:

```
var customers = XDocument.Load(uri)
    .Root.Elements("customer")
    .Select(x => new Customer {
        Date = DateTime.ParseExact(x.Element("date").Value, "d MMM yyyy",
                                   CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
        Name = (string) x.Element("name"),
        Phone = (string) x.Element("phone")
    });
```

You might also want to add a call to `ToList()` after `Select`, if you want the whole list of customers for other reasons.

After this, the fact that the original data source was XML is irrelevant. You can then use `OrderByDescending` to sort by date with the most recent first, and `Take` to limit the results:

```
var recentCustomers = customers.OrderByDescending(c => c.Date)
                               .Take(4);
```

LINQ is a *very* useful technique for querying data. I strongly recommend that you learn more about is - search for information on MSDN, tutorials etc.

Comment: thanks alot but the problem is (A)My date is not formatted properly. (B)i want to return top 4 nodes based on date so for some customer node i have only date while name and phone elements do not exist

Comment: @user3718016: in comments you said it would be okay to change the date format. My code will already handle missing name and phone.

Comment: i thought you are talking about changing from the code

Comment: is there any way to change the date into right format ?

Comment: Well it should be a matter of changing whatever's *producing* the data. I'll give an alternative in my answer.

Comment: this is my element <date>22 Aug 2014</date> what can i add to change into proper format before adding into list because if i use the same format <date>22 Aug 2014</date> i am getting wrong datetime error

Comment: i like your solution but i am just wondering what i need to do to change the format. Should i create another list then change the format of date and put it into another list?

Comment: @user3718016: that should already work with the second piece of code I've given.

Comment: @user3718016: Once you've parsed it as a `DateTime`, it doesn't *have* a format. If you output it later on, you should use a better format - and if you can change whatever's creating the original file, that would be good to. But otherwise, you don't need to do anything.